# django: programmatic connection refused

Tags: python, django, web-services, http

I'm trying to test out this POST request that I've implemented on my django web server and I ran into quite the snag...

After running the server with:

> python manage.py runserver

I figured that the quickest and dirtiest way to do test out the POST is through telnet.

> telnet localhost 8000

gave me

```
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
```

Then I realized that if the connection is refused, then I won't even be able to do my GET requests through my client-side. When I try to access the page through my web browser (Chrome), I GET the proper json response, and even the POST uri goes through (though with no data...)

I then tried a programmatic approach by establishing a connection with Python's urllib2 but even that gave me a connection refused exception.

I'm a complete django noob so I feel like I'm just forgetting something basic here...
I will provide more server-specifications if you need.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand you correctly but I think what you are looking for is [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en), a chrome plugin to do the POST thing.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the postman suggestion. It works with GET but the POST still isn't working. I think it's related to the middleware stuff but I'm not sure...

Comment: @brianSan when using the post method of postman, you need to chose between the 'form-date', 'x-www-form-urlencoded' and the 'raw'. You can have a try. The choose buttons is right above the 'key-value' pair. See the picture above.